# Can squid cache for https requests?

Tags: ssl, https, cache, squid

Just as said in "[Can squid cache objects from HTTPS sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/436348/can-squid-cache-objects-from-https-sites)", to cache objects from `https` sites, one would need to use the SSL bump feature.

But, I can set `https` proxy as well as `http` one, even the SSL bump feature is *not* installed. Does that means setting https proxy only means it can only let the content passing through without caching?

- What is really happening without the SSL bump feature then?
- What is preventing it to cache files like https://some.sites/some/path/image.png, so the next time people request it, it can be served from cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless a proxy is intercepting the HTTPS traffic (i.e. [SSL bump](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump)) and thus gets access to the decrypted content, it cannot cache the traffic. When just being a non-intercepting HTTPS proxy squid will just build a tunnel to the final server whenever a client issues a CONNECT request and will forward all traffic without any changes. Even if the client would access the same resource again the proxy will not realize this since the traffic is encrypted differently, i.e. different encryption key and initialization vector. Similar it would not be possible to reply with a cached (encrypted) response since the encryption key used between client and final server would be different from the last access to this resource.